# case operand type does not match when clause operand type integer vs boolean athena

Tags: sql, case, amazon-athena, presto

I am trying to use case statement on an integer field in aws athena using sql and I am getting the error saying that case operand type does not match when clause operand type integer vs boolean. I have verified the field type is integer. Attaching the code below.

```
SELECT a.open_dt, 
Case a.terms_duration when a.terms_duration<=6 then '<=6'
    when a.terms_duration>6 and a.terms_duration<=12 then '6-12'
    when a.terms_duration>12 and a.terms_duration<=18 then '12-18'
    when a.terms_duration>18 and a.terms_duration<=36 then '18-36'
    when a.terms_duration>36 and a.terms_duration<=48 then '36-48'
    when a.terms_duration>48 and a.terms_duration<=60 then '48-60'
    when a.terms_duration>60 then '60+'
    Else 'Missing' END
    FROM sx06grp.sx06am_pmnt_sbfe_crdb_sampleno_1_hp a limit 10;
```

Here is the Error

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
SELECT a.open_dt, 
Case a.terms_duration when a.terms_duration<=6 then '<=6'
    when a.terms_duration>6 and a.terms_duration<=12 then '6-12'
    when...

[Simba][AthenaJDBC](100071) An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. SYNTAX_ERROR: line 2:23: CASE operand type does not match WHEN clause operand type: integer vs boolean [SQL State=HY000, DB Errorcode=100071]
1 statement failed.

Execution time: 0.6s
```

Comment: just replace `Case a.terms_duration when` with `Case when`

Comment: Hey @BarbarosÖzhan that worked. Please add that as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are boolean expressions following each `when` clauses while expression after `case` clause is of mismatching type.

Indeed you don't need an expression following `case` clause for your aim of current case, then just get rid of that such as

```sql
CASE 
  WHEN a.terms_duration <= 6 THEN
   '<=6'
  WHEN a.terms_duration >  6 AND a.terms_duration <= 12 THEN
   '6-12'
  WHEN a.terms_duration > 12 AND a.terms_duration <= 18 THEN
   '12-18'
  WHEN a.terms_duration > 18 AND a.terms_duration <= 36 THEN
   '18-36'
  WHEN a.terms_duration > 36 AND a.terms_duration <= 48 THEN
   '36-48'
  WHEN a.terms_duration > 48 AND a.terms_duration <= 60 THEN
   '48-60'
  WHEN a.terms_duration > 60 THEN
   '60+'
  ELSE
   'Missing'
 END
```